# What DB changes require a re-syncing of dbml linq objects?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, vb.net-2010

What database table schema changes will require me to locate all the programs where I used a dbml file based on the table and re-compile? I love the advantages of linq but this maintenance seems like a big productivity hit.

Comment: Maybe put the dbml in a single project, and then reuse that project across your programs

Comment: Addressing this, is there any way to automatically update the dll used by client apps if there is a new version of it. I am using Click Once for the app deployment. If I could somehow pull down a new version of a dll the app is using every time there is one then I wouldn't have to recompile each time. Of course I could only do this for changes that would not affect the app, but this would keep the linq classes happily in sync with the DB if I seperated them all into the dll. I could just update the one "linq" dll instead of all my projects that reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two kinds of changes will require you to re-sync the DBML and recompile your app

1: changes you want to incorporate in your code

Eg: you added a new field and you want to edit/show this field in your code. Obviously, the L2S classes cannot know about the new field so you would have to resync them

2: changes that will break your existing code

Eg: If you change the datatype from varchar to int and your existing code does not know this, it will crash at runtime when inserting a string in your int fields.

> I love the advantages of linq but this maintenance seems like a big
>   productivity hit.

Not really, any other data approach would need some kind of maintenance in these cases.

Comment: There is at least one scenario where straight sql access to the DB will continue to work whereas the dbml/linq approach won't. If a field is removed from a table and I am not using that field in a particular program (actually happens quite often around here), straight sql updates (delineating fields) to the table will continue to work. But using linq if a field is removed and my code tries to create an object from a record in the table w/o recompiling it will cause a crash because there will be no corresponding field for the property it is trying to create.

Comment: That is an interesting use case. Why was that field in the database anyway woud be my first question... And if it was already there and it is never used, why remove it?  But in this case it will fail so you are right.

Comment: I'm coming around on the idea that using linq doesn't require much if any more maintenance than other DB methods. The few cases, like the one I cited about dropping a field, requiring recompiling are probably pretty rare - or should be :) and like Pleun implied result from intermediate table designs, so even if it didn't crash it would probably be best to re-attach the table after finalizing table schemas anyway to clean up the code.